# how do i add a parent key to json object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to add a wrapping key to an entire JSON object with javascript and having some issues. For example:

```
var obj = { "name" : "Bob", "city" : "Detroit", "state" : "MI" };
```

I want to add a parent key to this so it would eventually output as:

```
{ "personalization" : { "name" : "Bob", "city" : "Detroit", "state" : "MI" } }
```

Since the var obj is dynamically built I thought of doing something like this, but it doesn't like having a var in there:

```
var obj = { "name" : "Bob", "city" : "Detroit", "state" : "MI" };
var obj2 = { "personalization" : obj };
```

Comment: There is no JSON in the above. Just JavaScript. JSON is a non-source-code *textual* notation.

Comment: what does `doesn't like having a var` mean?

Comment: Couldn't you just do the manual wrapping if you don't want an object in there? `var obj = {"personalization": { "name" : "Bob", "city" : "Detroit", "state" : "MI" } };`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a comment, but comments can't have Stack Snippets, so it's a CW.

Your example at the end is just fine, there's no problem there. That's exactly how you'd take an object and make it a property of another object you're creating via an object initializer:

```js
var obj = { "name" : "Bob", "city" : "Detroit", "state" : "MI" };
var obj2 = { "personalization" : obj };
snippet.log(obj2.personalization.name); // Shows Bob
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: ha, yeah you're right. i went back through my code and realized i had it as { "personalization" : {obj}}; thanks for pointing that point.