# How to add travel word to JSON?

Tags: android

my json is
{[{"key1":"value1","key2":"valu2"},{“ key3":"value3","key4":"valu4”}]}

How to change the above text as follows. Thank you for helping my friends

{"travel": [{"key1":"value1","key2":"valu2"},{ key3":"value3","key4":"value4}]}

Comment: This question needs refinement. Android application development supports many languages so, in which are you trying to update this JSON?

Comment: Your original string is not valid JSON.

Comment: As Henry already pointed out this is not JSON. Some quotes are missing, others use the wrong character as quote: `”`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do i add a parent key to json object using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625981/how-do-i-add-a-parent-key-to-json-object-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Your original String is not a valid JSON for two reasons:
1 we can see some invalid quotes 
2 elements inside a json object must have keys.

so assuming that your String is correct to achieve what you need in java you can do the following:

```java
String string="{[{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"valu2\"},{\" key3\":\"value3\",\"key4\":\"valu4\"}]}";

        StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder(string);
        stringBuilder.insert(1,"\"travel\":");
        String json=stringBuilder.toString();
```

You just insert your key after the first character. Hope this will help.